# How can I hide or modify page name

Tags: templates

This might more be a Drupal rather than a CiviCRM question but how do I hide or modify the name of a page like in this example? It's CiviCRM home page here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide on that particular page one option is to add this in css/extras.css

```
body.page-civicrm-dashboard div#tabs-wrapper h1 {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [word replacement](https://www.cividesk.com/blog/did-you-know-any-word-or-phrase-civicrm-can-be-replaced-another-one). Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Word Replacements.

For some strings it works but for others you need to add some JS to replace the words or hooks to change the page titles.

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, I had already tried this option and it was not succcessful.

Comment: Do you want to make more space on the page, make the tiltle smaller or not display, rather than change the spelling, is that the aim? Restyling is the answer. Alternatively you could see if https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch is more suited to your aesthetics.

Comment: thank you Sean Kenny, I didn't know about this extension/theme. I will have a look.

Comment: Actually I want to change the page name to be named by our customer's company name. Where can I modify this?